# Hazel - Add "my file" to folder if folder name contains "example"

Tags: macos, applescript

Using Hazel or applescript i would like to implement the following workflow:
I want to monitor a "home" folder for any "new" folders.
If "new" folders are created and their name contains "example" 
and 
if "new" folder does not already contain "my file.txt"
then 
add "my file.txt" (located in "my file" folder) to "new" folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a rule like this in Hazel:

[image]

The first embedded script is `[[ ! -e $1/my\ file.txt ]]` and the second embedded script is `cp ~/my\ file/my\ file.txt "$1"`.

You could also create a folder action with Automator. Choose the Folder Action template, add a Run Shell Script action, set "Pass input" to "as arguments", and use a script like this:

`for f; do [[ -d $f && $f = *example* && ! -e $f/my\ file.txt ]] && cp ~/my\ file/my\ file.txt "$f"; done`